# liquibase:changelogSync giving NullPointerException

Tags: maven, liquibase

I am trying to upload the data to oracle db using changelogSync and I am getting nullpointer exception. My liquibase version is 3.6.2 and using maven to execute liquibase goals. This data I extracted from another db using generateChangeLog in xml format.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

mvn -X clean liquibase:changelogSync  -f backup_pom.xml

Here is my pom:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mytests.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-liquibase</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
          <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                  <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
          </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
        <configuration>
                <propertyFile>
                        C:/Users/ygupta/Tools/db/liquibase.properties
                </propertyFile>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here are the maven logs:

```
[INFO] Successfully released change log lock
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.784 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-07T16:35:56+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:changelogSync (default-cli) on project my-liquibase: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:changelogSync failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:changelogSync (default-cli) on project my-liquibase: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:changelogSync failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:changelogSync failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init (StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:127)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables (Liquibase.java:1219)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.changeLogSync (Liquibase.java:873)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseChangeLogSyncMojo.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseChangeLogSyncMojo.java:19)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:366)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

**UPDATED:**
I was incorrectly using changelogSync, but even if I run update goal, I get same error. I would like to emphasize that generateChangelog's output xml was not in correct xml format and had special characters. So I had to remove them manually before running any other liquibase plugin's goal. But after removing those special character , I get NullPointerException.

```
    [INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:***/p**od@docker-ygupta.domain:1522/ORCL
INFO 10/12/18 10:13 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
SEVERE 10/12/18 10:13 AM:liquibase: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'databaseChangeLog'.
INFO 10/12/18 10:13 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
INFO 10/12/18 10:13 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

    [INFO] Successfully released change log lock
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  7.635 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-10T09:21:29+11:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update (default-cli) on project my-liquibase: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update (default-cli) onproject my-liquibase: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init (StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:127)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables (Liquibase.java:1219)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update (Liquibase.java:193)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update (Liquibase.java:179)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update (Liquibase.java:334)
        at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseUpdate.doUpdate (LiquibaseUpdate.java:33)
        at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.performLiquibaseTask (AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.java:30)
        at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:366)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake is that the `changelogSync` command will not upload data to the database. That command is intended to be used when you have made changes to a database some other way (using Oracle SQL developer or SQL Server Management studio or something like that) and you have corresponding changes in your changelog.xml, and you want to make sure that the DATABASECHANGELOG table reflects that the two are in sync.

If you have something in a changelog.xml that you want deployed to a database, you would use the liquibase `update` command.

That said, I am not sure why you are getting that Null Pointer Exception. The line of code in question has several places it could generate that. It could be that the DATABASECHANGELOG table doesn't exist at all, or that it exists but doesn't have the correct columns.

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/8ee4607c7a0c99c5de9538c0ca850473b300576e/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/changelog/StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java#L127

```
    if (!(this.getDatabase() instanceof SQLiteDatabase)) {
        DataType type = changeLogTable.getColumn("LIQUIBASE").getType();
        if (type.getTypeName().toLowerCase().startsWith("varchar")) {
            Integer columnSize = type.getColumnSize();
            liquibaseColumnNotRightSize = (columnSize != null) && (columnSize < 20);
        } else {
            liquibaseColumnNotRightSize = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. But I get same issues with Liquibase:update as well. With Liquibase:generateChangelog , the xml I generated had special characters like - "&#0;" and update was complaining of special characters. Now when I remove them, liquibase:update gives Null pointer exception.

Comment: I feel I am doing something wrong here. I noticed in maven logs that I am getting this error: "SEVERE 10/12/18 10:13 AM:liquibase: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'databaseChangeLog'.". Please can you share your feedback

Comment: From that error message it sounds like liquibase is either not finding your changelog file or the changelog file isn't properly formatted. It also sounds like you may have confusion about the liquibase 'life cycle', and what each of the different commands is used for. You mention several commands, but it isn't clear what your overall goal is.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My overall goal is to migrate data from one oracle db to another oracle db. I used generateChangelog to get data in changelog.xml and now I want to deploy that data into another db. Please correct me if I should do it any other way?

Comment: While Liquibase can be used for data migration, it is not the best tool for that. Its primary use case is managing schema (structural) change over time. If your goal is to do a one-time data migration, especially from one Oracle DB to another, it would be far better to just use the Oracle backup/restore tools. If you want to do ongoing data migration (and especially if the source and target databases have different schemas), there are ETL tools that work better than Liquibase does - look at Pentaho Data Migration for an example of that.

Comment: I was missing 
 <liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName>DBCHANGELOG_LQ3</liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName>"

Now its working. But now another problem, for generateChangelog I have a specific list of tables which are to be extracted. The changelog.xml dumps the table in alphabetical sequence which is creating problem as some tables are dependent on each other and have to added in a certain sequence. How can we make generatechangelog dump tables in order which is given in pom?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to control the order that liquibase generates changesets when using generateChangelog. What I would do is generate the changelog, and then re-order the changesets as needed (manually, using a text editor or if you have an XML-aware editor, using something like that).

Comment: I am trying to use liquibase maven diff to generate diffChangelog between the two databases. http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_diff.html
 I am curious why we have to give changeLogFile parameter? We are giving two databases details, then what is changelogFile for?

Comment: In that case, you are telling it where to generate the changelog file.

Comment: No, there are two options changelogFile and diffChangelogfile. Latter is the one where diff is actually generated, then what is changelogfile for? I am asking because its mandatory. Clearly I am missing something because diff is not working for me.